# PHP renaming files sometimes fails

Tags: php

Let me start with saying that I am not 100% certain that this is a PHP-question. It could be a "filesystem question", I don't know.

Here goes...I am using plupload to upload files on a work website. The upload itself works flawlessly, but then I run into trouble. The website is hosted on a linux server with several other boxes mounted, whereof one file server (Windows) and another server where the files are processed (let's call this the process-server, which is also a Windows box). I.e. there are three separate file systems involved.

```
if (!is_dir($processServerPath)) {
    error_log("Filehandler: $processServerPath is not a directory");
    if (!mkdir($processServerPath, 0777, true)) {
        error_log("Filehandler: $processServerPath could not be created"); // This never happens. $processServerPath is always created successfully
    }
}

if (!is_dir($processServerPathTmp)) {
    error_log("Filehandler: $processServerPathTmp is not a directory");
    if (!mkdir($processServerPathTmp, 0777, true)) {
        error_log("Filehandler: $processServerPathTmp could not be created"); // This never happens. $processServerPathTmp is always created successfully
    }
}

if (copy("{$filePath}.part", $fileServerPath.$filename)) {  // File copied from webserver to file server. This NEVER fails.
    if (!copy($fileServerPath.$filename,$processServerPathTmp.$filename)) { // File copied from file server to process server tmp. This NEVER fails.
        error_log("Filehandler: Could not copy $filename from file server to process server tmp");  
    } else {
        if (!rename($processServerPathTmp.$filename,$processServerPath.$filename)) {  // File is moved from process server tmp to process server watched folder. This fails about 10%-20% of the time.
            error_log("Filehandler: Could not move $filename from process server tmp to process server");
        }
    }
}
```

First copy: When the file upload is finished, the file(s) are copied from the webserver tmp-folder to the file server. This NEVER fails.

Second copy: Once on the file server, I proceeded to copy the file from the file server to a watched folder the process-server. This failed about 40% of the time. I.e. it WORKS more often than not, but not 100% of the time. The only error I ever get is "No such file or directory in...". I do know for a fact, however, that this is wrong. The directory is there. I have done extensive logging if this procedure and watched it happen in front of my eyes. The directory NEVER exists when the upload starts, but is created before I get to the part where this error occurs.

Considering the possibility that the file is picked up from the watched folder before it is finished copying, I decided to FIRST copy the file to a NON-watched folder on the processor-server and then renaming it from the non-watched folder to the watched folder, since copying a file between file systems DOES take time. However, once on the correct file system, the rename:ing of the file is instant as the file is not physically moved. It's just file file system pointer that is changed.
This improved the success rate greatly, but not to 100%. Now I suffer this problem perhaps 10% of the time.

What I do not understand is how this works most of the time but SOMETIMES fails. There is no consistency, this error occurs on large files and small files alike. This is all done on our intranet, so "slow internet connection" is not an issue. As you can see, the files are given a new name when copied to the file server. $filename contains a valid filename, without spaces, special characters and other weird stuff.

Is it possible that the copy command returns true before the file is finished copying and allows the code continue to run? I thought I would not enter an if-statement block until the file was successfully copied and done. Is it thus possible that the rename executes and tries to rename the file before the copy is finished?

Comment: I suspect the process that monitors the watch folder interferes with moving the files. Maybe it locks the folder while it's reading it. If you move the file to a non-watched folder, does that still fails occasionally?

Comment: You mean move file from file server to process server tmp, then to another process server directory and THEN to the watched folder? I have not tried that, but it seems a bit much. I'll give it a try, though.

Comment: I mean move it to a non watched folder just to determine if the problem is the watch process or something else like a connection-error or permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was too cocky claiming that the "does not exist" error was incorrect.  If you get the error "does not exist", that's probably so.

This is what happened:

1. The script checks if all directories involved exist. They never do, so they are always created. I watched this happen, thus I "knew" that they existed.
   Create fileserver/targetDirectory/, processServer/tempDirectory/, processServer/WatchedFolder/targetDirectory/
2. The files were uploaded to the web server. This took from a few seconds to half a minute, for large files
3. The files were copied from the web server to fileserver/targetDirectory/ (this always worked)
4. The files were copied from fileserver/targetDirectory/ to processServer/tempDirectory, to avoid copying to the watched folder. (This always worked)
5. Then... sometimes failure when moving from processServer/tempDirectory/ to processServer/WatchedFolder/targetDirectory/

The failure occurred because the watching process scans processServer/WatchedFolder/ for files that have not changed in size the last 15 seconds. Remember that I created the processServer/WatchedFolder/targetDirectory before I even started the file upload! If the upload took "too long", the watching process noticed that the targetDirectory (just another file, after all) had not changed size the last 15 seconds and deleted it. So sometimes when I got to step 5 above, processServer/WatchedFolder/targetDirectory existed, sometimes it did not!